# Did Debug=(os.getenv("DEBUG_VALUE")=='True') but still showing debug info on all devices

Tags: django, heroku

I have hide my debug value and security key in env variable. but after accessing a unknown page on my website. it shows debug information. what am I doing wrong?

```
# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = os.getenv("SECRET_KEY")


# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!

DEBUG = (os.getenv("DEBUG_VALUE") == 'True')
```

DEBUG_VALUE = 'True' in env var.

and I have done `heroku config:set Secret_Key="***" and Debug_value='True'`

Comment: ...why would you set `Debug_value='True'` if you want to _disable_ debug? Anyway, please make sure that the casing of your environment variable matches what you are trying to use in your `settings.py`. I.e., they should both be `DEBUG_VALUE` (more idiomatic), or both `Debug_value`, not one of each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set the `DEBUG` to true. So the Django will show debug information. If you want to disable it, simply set `DEBUG_VALUE='False'`, or any other value (based on your settings), in your Heroku config.

Comment: It Now says not found on unknown pages, but it stopped showing the debug info to me also. I ran os.environ['DEBUG_VALUE'] == 'True' in cmd and it returns True. Then why doesnt it show debug info to me.

Comment: When you set the `DEBUG` to `False`, you won't get details detail information about the errors, as in production. See [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-DEBUG) for more information on that. Based on the "not found" error, the `DEBUG` should be `False` now.